# How to do bubble plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I've searched for many ways to do bubble plot as **Mathematica** but with no worthy result, all what I've found is plotting with variant *marker size*, which is not a good solution as marker size value is bounded.

Is there anyway to do bubble plot in **Matlab** like the following plot of **Mathematica** ?

[image: Bubble plot image]

Comment: Apparently the 3-argument form of [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) can do a bubble plot.

Comment: The 3rd argument is marker size (circle size), and it has a bounded value which won't be a good solution for the scale of very large circle versus small ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't see what's wrong with [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6805-BUBBLE%20PLOT). Example:

```
x = 80 * randn(1, 30); 
y = 80 * randn(size(x));
r = randi(1500, size(x));
c = randi(10, size(x));
scatter(x, y, r, c, 'filled', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k')
```

This yielded for me the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, this plot shows both very large and very small circles.

Comment: You are right. And I'm sorry because I didn't investigate it well :).

Comment: @SamehKamal: You could sort the data by circle size before plotting to get a good stacking.

Comment: @Jonas .. Actually I'm revising some plotting functionality as I am going to apply them on geographical reporting using `Matlab GUI`, so circles will be plotted dependent on the location.

Comment: @Jonas That's a good suggestion. Sorting has to be done in descending order, of course, so that the larger circles are plotted first (and consequently, underneath the smaller circles).